# Matplotlib axis custom intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

For a plot, I need the y-axis to be between -800 and +20 with evenly spaced intervals intervals for approximately the following ranges:

`-1000 to -100, -100 to -50, -50 to -20, -20 to 0, 0 to +20`

How can I do this? `plt.yscale` only allows using predefined scales like `linear`, `log` etc. as far as I know. I couldn't find how to create a custom scale.

I'm fine with some flexibility in the division of the y-axis but need it to roughly respect that. I'm even okay with using purely the log base 10 scale with `plt.yscale('log',basey=10)`, but this doesn't allow me to get negative numbers on the axis.

EDIT: using `plt.yscale('symlog',basey=10)` solves the problem of plotting negative log intervals. But if I did want to do it, how would I have a custom scale?

Comment: Look into formatters and locators

Comment: From a brief glance, these are for the ticker markers on the axis, and they don't change the scale on the axis. Please correct me if I am mistaken. I don't need to change the locations of the ticks. I need to change the scale so that the data is plotted differently.

Comment: It's "fake", but if you scale the data yourself and apply the right ticks, you get the same net effect